# Read file opened via FileReference in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have to browse for and open a file in AIR.
I can access the file via the File class:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("somefile.txt");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
```

And I can browse for a file via the FileReference class:

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.browse(allTypes);
```

But I cannot seem to get the file from the FileReference object into the File object.

There is no "path" member exposed when debugging the FileReference after opening it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [File#browseForOpen()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen%28%29) instead of `FileReference#browse()`, something like this:

```
private var f:File;

public function browseForRead():void {
    f = File.documentsDirectory;
    f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, readFile); 
    f.browseForOpen("Open file");
}

private function readFile(event:Event):void {
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(f, FileMode.READ);
    trace(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
}
```

`FileReference#browse()` is used for uploading files in web applications.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo @lukevanin